# "How to format cell based on data in sam column but previous row"

Tags: gs-conditional-formatting

I have a table for each week of the year with week number in column A. then for column B, C, D and E I have results for each person per week. I want to condtional format the cell based on the result of the previous week. eg week 3 is the same or higher than week 2, I want week 3 to be green, but if then week 4 is lower than week 3 to show as red.

I have tried multiple different custom formula's based on different examples i've seen but none are working

Answer (score 0):

Please select from B3 to the row of the last cell in your table and ColumnE (assuming you have a header row) and: Format > Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... Custom formula is and:

```
=B3>=B2
```

with green highlighting and repeat with instead:

```
=B3<B2
```

and red highlighting.